# Make 3.3V from any type of battery cell

Tags: batteries, low-power

I'm trying to make a universal power circuit for STM32L0-based project. I want to use any type of batteries - alkaline or li-ion either (single cell). Can you help me choose the best converter?

It should work in both directions because input voltage will be from 0.9V to 4.2V.

I have a prototype on the breadboard using two converters - the first boosts Vin to 5V, the second drops it back to 3V3. It is not very effective and 5V is not needed all the time (I will make it by separate boost converter.)

Comment: Useful search term : buck-boost converter

Comment: It also depends on the current draw and the reliability you need. Tiny cheap, low current, low reliability modules are available online from you know where. However, high reliability branded modules are expensive.

Comment: Have you thought of using a SEPIC converter it boosts and bucks.

Comment: All buck-boost Ive found have 1.8-V minimum input voltage for start-up. Do you know one that have at least 1V?